# Install MS SQL drivers on AWS Linux2023 ARM

Tags: sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install pdo_sqlsrv.so and sqlsrv.so on AWS Linux2023. I'm downloading the drivers from the MS GitHub page https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases. I've tried CentOS8-8.1 and CentOS7-7.1, but all I get is:

```
tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing I need a different version of the driver or maybe there isn't an ARM version?

Comment: Are you actually on an ARM instance? (That could be problematic, yes.) What commands are you running while trying to install?

Comment: Have you read through [Comparing Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux 2023](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html) yet to see how it differs from Amazon Linux 2 otherwise?

Comment: I did read through the documentation. I downloaded my best guess on which drivers to use (RHEL 9 if I remember right) ... but ultimately I decided to throw in the towel and rebuild the servers on x86 Amazon Linux 2. Took about an hour. Sheesh.